# Ruby API Error Handling

Tags: ruby, api, hash

I'm having problems parsing API results for a specific record that I'm hoping to get assistance with.  I have an array of property addresses that I'm making API calls on to gather additional information.  My script works fine on the first 57th address and parses the results successfully.  For some reason the 58th response is slightly different (in HTTParty) and throws an error that kills my script.  The error is as follows:

```
/home/pjw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/httparty-0.14.0/lib/httparty/response.rb:81:in `dig': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
    from /home/pjw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/httparty-0.14.0/lib/httparty/response.rb:81:in `method_missing'
    from automate_backup.rb:46:in `block in <main>'
    from automate_backup.rb:40:in `map'
    from automate_backup.rb:40:in `<main>'
```

The piece of code that trips the error looks like this: (last line of below code)

```
property_results.map do |p|
    address = URI::encode(p[:street])
    zip = URI::encode(p[:zip])
  puts "working on #{p[:street]}"

re_results = HTTParty.get("http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetDeepSearchResults.htm?zws-id=#{zwsid}&address=#{address}&citystatezip=#{zip}&rentzestimate=true")
      p[:zpid] = re_results.dig("searchresults", "response", "results", "result", "zpid")
```

Apparently the HTTP response in Ruby is handled different than the 57 others and a "[" is inserted inside the hash (see API response below, line #7) which kills my `dig` method.  Looking at this response in [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) looks the same as all of the other responses (see image at bottom), however, Ruby for some reason parses it differently and inserts an array inside of the Hash.

I'm not experienced enough in Ruby to know how to put error control and code around this issue.  If anyone can help me understand why this would happen, or more importantly, how to code around it I would greatly appreciate it.  The API response I'm having problems with is as follows:

```
{"searchresults"=>
  {"request"=>{"address"=>"1 Sunset Pkwy", "citystatezip"=>"28801"},
   "message"=>{"text"=>"Request successfully processed", "code"=>"0"},
   "response"=>
    {"results"=>
      {"result"=>
        [{"zpid"=>"125699479",
          "links"=>
           {"homedetails"=>"http://www.realestatelist.com/homedetails/1-Sunset-Pkwy-Gastonia-NC-28801/125699479_zpid/",
            "graphsanddata"=>
             "http://www.realestatelist.com/homedetails/1-Sunset-Pkwy-Gastonia-NC-28801/125699479_zpid/#charts-and-data",
            "mapthishome"=>"http://www.realestatelist.com/homes/125699479_zpid/",
            "comparables"=>"http://www.realestatelist.com/homes/comps/125699479_zpid/"},
          "address"=>
           {"street"=>"1 Sunset Pkwy",
            "zipcode"=>"28801",
            "city"=>"Gastonia",
            "state"=>"NC",
            "latitude"=>"35.609455",
            "longitude"=>"-82.545562"},
          "FIPScounty"=>"37021",
          "useCode"=>"SingleFamily",
          "taxAssessmentYear"=>"2015",
          "taxAssessment"=>"442000.0",
          "yearBuilt"=>"1926",
          "lotSizeSqFt"=>"36590",
          "finishedSqFt"=>"6423",
          "bathrooms"=>"4.5",
          "bedrooms"=>"4",
          "lastSoldDate"=>"03/03/2015",
          "lastSoldPrice"=>{"__content__"=>"455000", "currency"=>"USD"},
          "zestimate"=>
           {"amount"=>{"__content__"=>"1141085", "currency"=>"USD"},
            "last_updated"=>"11/29/2016",
            "oneWeekChange"=>{"deprecated"=>"true"},
            "valueChange"=>{"__content__"=>"-10785", "duration"=>"30", "currency"=>"USD"},
            "valuationRange"=>
             {"low"=>{"__content__"=>"182574", "currency"=>"USD"}, "high"=>{"__content__"=>"1198139", "currency"=>"USD"}},
            "percentile"=>"0"},
          "rentzestimate"=>
           {"amount"=>{"__content__"=>"5159", "currency"=>"USD"},
            "last_updated"=>"11/30/2016",
            "oneWeekChange"=>{"deprecated"=>"true"},
            "valueChange"=>{"__content__"=>"-236", "duration"=>"30", "currency"=>"USD"},
            "valuationRange"=>
             {"low"=>{"__content__"=>"3869", "currency"=>"USD"}, "high"=>{"__content__"=>"9802", "currency"=>"USD"}}},
          "localRealEstate"=>
           {"region"=>
             {"zindexValue"=>"239,400",
              "links"=>
               {"overview"=>"http://www.realestatelist.com/local-info/NC-Gastonia/r_50779/",
                "forSaleByOwner"=>"http://www.realestatelist.com/Gastonia-nc/fsbo/",
                "forSale"=>"http://www.realestatelist.com/Gastonia-nc/"},
              "name"=>"Gastonia",
              "id"=>"50779",
              "type"=>"city"}}},
         {"zpid"=>"2112713843",
          "links"=>
           {"homedetails"=>"http://www.realestatelist.com/homedetails/1-Sunset-Pkwy-Gastonia-NC-28801/2112713843_zpid/",
            "mapthishome"=>"http://www.realestatelist.com/homes/2112713843_zpid/",
            "comparables"=>"http://www.realestatelist.com/homes/comps/2112713843_zpid/"},
          "address"=>
           {"street"=>"1 Sunset Pkwy",
            "zipcode"=>"28801",
            "city"=>"Gastonia",
            "state"=>"NC",
            "latitude"=>"35.609455",
            "longitude"=>"-82.545585"},
          "FIPScounty"=>nil,
          "useCode"=>"SingleFamily",
          "yearBuilt"=>"1926",
          "lotSizeSqFt"=>"36590",
          "finishedSqFt"=>"9297",
          "bathrooms"=>"10.0",
          "bedrooms"=>"8",
          "zestimate"=>
           {"amount"=>{"__content__"=>"2365036", "currency"=>"USD"},
            "last_updated"=>"11/29/2016",
            "oneWeekChange"=>{"deprecated"=>"true"},
            "valueChange"=>{"__content__"=>"22810", "duration"=>"30", "currency"=>"USD"},
            "valuationRange"=>
             {"low"=>{"__content__"=>"780462", "currency"=>"USD"}, "high"=>{"__content__"=>"2483288", "currency"=>"USD"}},
            "percentile"=>"0"},
          "rentzestimate"=>
           {"amount"=>{"__content__"=>"10676", "currency"=>"USD"},
            "last_updated"=>"11/30/2016",
            "oneWeekChange"=>{"deprecated"=>"true"},
            "valueChange"=>{"__content__"=>"-192", "duration"=>"30", "currency"=>"USD"},
            "valuationRange"=>
             {"low"=>{"__content__"=>"7153", "currency"=>"USD"}, "high"=>{"__content__"=>"20284", "currency"=>"USD"}}},
          "localRealEstate"=>
           {"region"=>
             {"zindexValue"=>"239,400",
              "links"=>
               {"overview"=>"http://www.realestatelist.com/local-info/NC-Gastonia/r_50779/",
                "forSaleByOwner"=>"http://www.realestatelist.com/Gastonia-nc/fsbo/",
                "forSale"=>"http://www.realestatelist.com/Gastonia-nc/"},
              "name"=>"Gastonia",
              "id"=>"50779",
              "type"=>"city"}}}]}},
   "schemaLocation"=>
    "http://www.realestatelist.com/static/xsd/SearchResults.xsd http://www.realestateliststatic.com/vstatic/a7043fc/static/xsd/SearchResults.xsd"}}
```

I know that I can access the value I need by `zillow["searchresults"]["response"]["results"]["result"][0].dig("zpid")`
However the typical response I receive from the API looks like the following:  NOTICE:  There is no bracket "[" in front of "zpid" tag.

```
=> {"searchresults"=>
  {"request"=>{"address"=>"438 Barrington Dr", "citystatezip"=>"28803"},
   "message"=>{"text"=>"Request successfully processed", "code"=>"0"},
   "response"=>
    {"results"=>
      {"result"=>
        {"zpid"=>"96352377",
```

Postman Image of a normal (good) response, and the bad one from above, shows everything exactly the same
[image]

Comment: That API response isn't JSON.

Comment: @Schwern, thanks.  I've corrected the title.  Any idea on how to handle error control around this type of issue?  Thanks!

Comment: Looks like Sergii K has you covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value of `dig("searchresults", "response", "results", "result")` is an array. When you do next "digging", internally it calls `["zpid"]` on that array. Of course, ruby "expects" integer instead of "zpid" string. That's the reason.

**UPDATE**
You can save it like this:

```
zpid = re_results.dig('searchresults', 'response', 'results', 'result')
p[:zpid] = if zpid.is_a?(Array)
            zpid.map { |o| o['zpid'] }
           else
             zpid['zpid']
           end
```

But in that case, you'll need to apply same `if/else` for other fields.

Better approach is to always "wrap" `re_results.dig('searchresults', 'response', 'results', 'result')` to the array:

```
collection = [re_results.dig('searchresults', 'response', 'results', 'result')].flatten
```

In that case you'll always expect same data type.

Comment: Hmmmm, OK, how would I go about correcting this error? Is there a way to error handle around it?....I'm curious why all the others API responses work fine, and this one fails...I'll have to check if they use the same format.

Comment: Do you need to save all array elements or just first one? This issue can be solved in (at least) two ways.

Comment: I'll need to save a handful of the elements.